# Save error in DML operation

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

If two errors are encountered during a DML operation affecting 100,000 records, say one error at 25,000th record and another at 98,000th record, how can I save those errors without saving any DML operation?

Comment: You will have to write a autonomous transaction for this.

Comment: Do you mean [the error logging clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF55097)? What kind of errors do you mean, and do you want the other 999,998 operations to go through or fail? (Not really sure what 'without saving any DML' means).

Comment: Also how your code will run further when the error occurred at line 25000the record. Can you post your code.

Comment: @Raj:- suppose I need to insert a table from other table and face error 'target length is not sufficient'  at 25000th and 98000th records.

Comment: You can capture this at line 25000 using autonomous transaction. Please see the code below: the code will break there. I just wanted to see how are you coding so that your code is moving ahead ..Declare
  v_dummy number:0;
  procedure insertit is
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
  begin

    insert into testtab (a) values (-1);
    commit;
  end;
begin


 For recs in (select a from testtab)
  loop
   
  <DML Operation>
      
  end loop;
 
 exception
  when XXXX then
    insertit;
    raise;
end;

Comment: @Raj_Te - isn't that reinventing [built-in error logging](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9014.htm#BCEGDJDJ), but forcing the DML to be run inside PL/SQL?

Comment: @AlexPoole.I appreciate your approach. I have never used it however. Also when i read the article I found that if we want to use this clause we need to define our constraints when we create our table and error will be captured depending on that constraints. I may be wrong as well.